# protect flv video file

Tags: flex3, air, flv

I have a flv file,and want to play from only from AIR application.
Now i need to protect my flv file in such a way that it cant be opened or played by 
any other existing flv player in the world.If some one doubleclicked that flv file then 
action will be zero or not played by existing flv player in the world and only played from 
my own player.
how can i solve this?

Answer (score 5):

You cant really solve this.

1. Anyone can simply record the screen and audio circumventing any of your tools.
2. You could host the file on a streaming service which will steam the file via RTMP which is harder to crack but is a) expensive to host b) point 1 applies.
3. You could probably save the file with the extension .zip, its still a FLV file and you can just tell air to load this FLV just change the path name. This is sort of security through obscurity, point 1 still applies.  Someone will probably get that it is a FLV or video due to the very large file size.
4. If you makes lots of money you can write you own DRM video player for all platforms. But maybe focusing on making money from your idea first than losing a lot of time because 1. alwys applies.

Answer (score 0):

Except from hosting the file online, I am not aware of any built-in way of protecting an FLV file. I guess there should be some commercial solutions, or you could try to encrypt it yourself, but I think that would be over-complicating your application.

The best way I could think about, even if it's a bit "dirty", would be to embed the file in your AIR application.